# Error connecting mariadb - node.js?

Tags: node.js, mariadb

I am using `MariaDB` in my node.js application. I am having the following code

```
         var nodeMaria = require('node-mariadb');

         var connection = nodeMaria.createConnection({
             driverType: nodeMaria.DRIVER_TYPE_HANDLER_SOCKET,
             host:'localhost',
             port:9998
         });

         connection.on('error', function(err){
             console.log(err);
             process.exit(1);
         });

         connection.on('connect', function(){
             console.log("mariadb connected");
         });
```

#### Problem

After connecting the db, It is logging **"mariadb connected"**. 
  After that Application is breaking without throwing any error.

**Note:** I had handled the error in connection `connection.on('erorr',function(){});`

Any help will be great.

Comment: Note that you have a typo: you need to listen to the "error" event, not "erorr".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the application is closing, it doesn't necessarily mean that an error has occurred with connecting to MariaDB.
In fact, if there isn't anything keeping a node application explicitly open, it just closes after execution of the code.
What keeps a node application open? Event listeners. If you have an event listener listening for events, the node application doesn't close after finishing code execution. For example, if you have a http.listen command, which starts the web server and starts listening for incoming HTTP connections.